# Op-code decoding in an emulator

Tags: java, object-oriented, virtual-machine

I've written the larger part of an [emulator for a 6502 CPU](https://github.com/rossdrew/emuRox/tree/f2696e730af69645e7064c86409f7ce9502942d7) but my method of [op-code decoding](https://github.com/rossdrew/emuRox/tree/f2696e730af69645e7064c86409f7ce9502942d7/src/main/java/com/rox/emu/p6502/CPU.java#L116) is giving me concern, mainly because of how long the method is getting but also because I need a variable for each code, I need to declare them three times and I've stuck them all in a very [non-OO class](https://github.com/rossdrew/emuRox/tree/f2696e730af69645e7064c86409f7ce9502942d7/src/main/java/com/rox/emu/p6502/InstructionSet.java).  I wouldn't mind some scathing critique.

I've written it in a TDD fashion (in an effort to understand pure TDD) which has led to the simplest implementation with refactors only when necessary.  Even though I think this is probably the most efficient solution (making full use of the benefits of a switch statement), I'm thinking there's maybe a better way.

Extract:-

```
public void step() {
    System.out.println("\n*** STEP >>>");

    int accumulatorBeforeOperation = registers.getRegister(Registers.REG_ACCUMULATOR);
    int opCode = nextProgramByte();

    //Execute the opcode
    System.out.println("Instruction: " + InstructionSet.getOpCodeName(opCode) + "...");
    switch (opCode){
        case InstructionSet.OP_ASL_A: {
            int newFakeByte = registers.getRegister(Registers.REG_ACCUMULATOR) << 1;
            setCarryFlagBasedOn(newFakeByte);
            registers.setRegisterAndFlags(Registers.REG_ACCUMULATOR, newFakeByte);
        }
        break;

        case InstructionSet.OP_ASL_Z: {
            int location = nextProgramByte();
            int newFakeByte = memory.getByte(location) << 1;
            setCarryFlagBasedOn(newFakeByte);
            registers.setFlagsBasedOn(newFakeByte);
            memory.setByteAt(location, newFakeByte);
        }
        break;
        ...
        case InstructionSet.OP_DEY:
            registers.decrementRegisterWithFlags(Registers.REG_Y_INDEX);
            break;

        case InstructionSet.OP_LDX_I:
            registers.setRegisterAndFlags(Registers.REG_X_INDEX, nextProgramByte());
            break;

        case InstructionSet.OP_LDX_Z:
            registers.setRegisterAndFlags(Registers.REG_X_INDEX, getByteOfMemoryAt(nextProgramByte()));
            break;
        ...
        default:
            throw new UnknownOpCodeException("Unknown 6502 OpCode:" + opCode + " encountered.", opCode);
    }
```

**Thoughts**

I've looked at storing op-codes as `Enum`s but it means reading bytes (in Javas case this is `int` represented bytes) and writing conversion code from raw byte to `Enum` but that seems unnecessary for the small maintainability improvement.

It seems excessive and not very OO to do it with a [class per op-code](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/147622/6502-cpu-emulator-in-java?rq=1).

Comment: Have you considered implementing this more like the instruction decoder works in the actual hardware?  That usually means looking at a few bits at a time to match against entire families of instructions - in fact that's the whole reason you see repeating patterns in the instruction set.  I've only used Z80 and 6800, but I wouldn't expect 6502 to be any different in that respect.

Comment: It's not different at all @TobySpeight.  
I did consider it but it means tearing each byte apart into sections then writing lookup tables.  I'd be sacrificing flexibility for authenticity.  I want it to function like a 6502 but be good Java design.  It's a tightrope :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I figured a [much nicer way](https://rossdrew.github.io//emulating-opcodes/) to deal with this.  Break it down into the repeatable elements, i.e. *Addressing Mode* and *Operation* then code them all separately and immutably, combining them in the right way to get all *OpCode*s.  Effectively doing functional programming in Java.

**First**: If you represent an operation, say ASL(*arithmatic shift left*) as an Enum (`Operation`), which has a parameter that is a lamba of a `@FunctionalInterface` (in this case called `AddressedValueInstruction`) and accepts two bytes and returns a result.
 (Note: `RoxByte` is just my custom implementation of a byte)

```
public enum Operation implements AddressedValueInstruction {
/** Shift all bits in byte left by one place, setting flags based on the result */
    ASL((a,r,m,v) -> {
        final RoxByte newValue = a.asl(v);
        r.setFlagsBasedOn(newValue);
        return newValue;
    }),

    ...

    @Override
    public RoxByte perform(Mos6502Alu alu, Registers registers, Memory memory, RoxByte value) {
        return instruction.perform(alu, registers, memory, value);
    }
```

**Second**: If you represent the Addressing Mode as an Enum then -similar to `Operation`- have one of the Enum parameters as a `@FunctionalInterface` (called `Addressable`) lambda you can say `MyEnum.address(AddressedValueInstruction)` which will address a value, then sent it to the given operation then address the result.

```
public enum AddressingMode implements Addressable {
    /** Expects no argument, operation will be performed using the Accumulator Register*/
    ACCUMULATOR("Accumulator", 1, (r, m, a, i) -> {
        final RoxByte value = r.getRegister(Registers.Register.ACCUMULATOR);
        r.setRegister(Registers.Register.ACCUMULATOR, i.perform(a, r, m, value));
    }),

    ...

    @Override
    public void address(Registers r, Memory m, Mos6502Alu alu, AddressedValueInstruction instruction) {
        address.address(r, m, alu, instruction);
    }
```

**Third**: This means you can create opcodes in the same way by creating combinations of addressing modes and operations with no specific code required, i.e. `ASL_ACCUMULATOR(ACCUMULATOR, ASL)` and it can be run with `ASL_ACCUMULATOR.perform()`

```
public enum OpCode implements Mos6502Instruction {
    ASL_A(0x0A, ACCUMULATOR, ASL),
    ...

    @Override
    public void perform(Mos6502Alu alu, Registers registers, Memory memory) {
        addressingMode.address(registers, memory, alu, operation::perform);
    }
```

This approach has the benefits of a class per opcode approach, without all the boiler plate.